# How to test an OTP-secured Django form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm building a Django application using the `django_otp` OTP extension, and I'm running into some issues with automated testing of forms.

Specifically, despite everything I've tried, attempts to call a form decorated with `otp_required` results in getting shown the 'you need to enable OTP on this account' redirect page.

I've made several attempts at implementing things suggested by google searches, such as [this one](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/issues/525) and several others.

Right now, during the TestCase `__init__` I create a user with the following code:

```py
        # Set up a user:
        self.testuser = User.objects.create(username='testuser')
        self.testuser.set_password('12345')
        self.testuser.is_superuser = True
        self.testuser.is_verified = True
        self.otp_device = self.testuser.staticdevice_set.create(name='Testdevice')
        self.otp_device.confirmed = True
        self.otp_device.save()
        self.testuser.save()
```

And when using a `Client` object to make a request:

```py
    def setup_client(self):
        client = Client()

        client.force_login(self.testuser)
        client.session.save()

        return client
```

The failing test case is:

```py
    def test_connection_create_form_no_circuit(self):
        testdata = baseData()
        client = testdata.setup_client()


        client_group = ClientGroup.objects.get(name='testgroup')
        context_id = Context.objects.get(name='testcontext').id
        bandwidth_id = BandwidthProfile.objects.get(name='testprofile').id
        conntype_id = ConnectionType.objects.get(name='testconntype').id
        postdata = {
            'id_enabled': True,
            'id_circuitless': True,
            'id_debug_info': False,
            'id_connectionref': 'Test 1234',
            'id_customer': '321',
            'id_install_address': '123 Stockton Bvd.',
            'id_carrierref': 'nil',
            'id_c_context': context_id,
            'id_c_bandwidthprofile': bandwidth_id,
            'id_c_connectiontype': conntype_id,
            'id_ppp_username': 'test_conn_123',
            'id_ppp_password': 'pass_54321',
            'id_ipv4_address': '1.2.3.4'
        }
        response = client.post('/radius/clientgroup/%d/connection/' % client_group.id,
                               postdata)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Rather than a 200 I'm getting a 403 and the 'You need to have OTP enabled on this login to see this page' template.

I'm fairly sure I'm doing something extremely simple wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out *what*.